# JS ругается на переменную

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в JS и очень хочу научиться писать на нем. Помогите решить очень банальную проблему. снизу мой код:

```
while (true){
  let number = prompt("Введите число. Оно должно быть больше или ровно 1")
  if(number < 1){
    alert("Введите правильно число!")
  }
  else{
    break;
  }
}
multiplicationTable(number);



function multiplicationTable(number){
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.write(1+i, "*", number, "=",(1+i) * number, "<br \/>")
  }
}
```

multiplicationTable(number);   <== Вот здесь он ругается, что  нет такой переменной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У переменных, объявленных через ключевое слово `let`, область видимости блочная. То есть они работают только в пределах своих скобок `{}`.

Объявите переменную `number` выше цикла:

```
let number;

while (true){
  number = prompt("Введите число. Оно должно быть больше или ровно 1")
  if(number < 1){
    alert("Введите правильно число!")
  }
  else{
    break;
  }
}

multiplicationTable(number);

function multiplicationTable(number){
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.write(1+i, "*", number, "=",(1+i) * number, "<br \/>")
  }
}
```